# Using jquery plugin in aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, jquery-plugins, jquery-steps

This is the first time im using a jquery plugin and i want to use this [jquery plugin](http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples#basic-form) into my aspx page.I havent seen any kind of documentation on how to use the plugin on the website.

Amy documentation on how to use the plugin will be very helpful

Comment: While adding ``.js`` and ``.css`` files to your Application, you must take care of their path and the control Id's, using to invoke ``javascript`` methods, make use of browser console. As mostly people stuck in these two things. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Download jQuery from http://jquery.com/download/

   And go to the link   Download the compressed, production jQuery 1.10.2
   and save the js as 
   jquery-1.10.2.min.js.

   Add this js to your project.
2. Download jQueryUi from  http://JqueryUi.com.   Uncomress this and Add ui and theme
   folder to your project.
3. Now in your page take reference of  jquery-1.10.2.min.js 
   By adding this you can use basic functionality of jQuery.
4. To use jQuery Controls, you need to take reference of

   jquery-ui.min.css from themes\base\minified folder

   jquery-ui.min.js from ui\minified folder

Note: 1. jquery-ui.min.js must be placed after jquery-1.10.2.min.js

```
  2. base is the default theme. you can download and use other themes as well
     you just need to change folder name in the reference to the css.

  3. You can also use uncompressed version to the jQuery code and debugging    
     during development
```

Comment: why should i download jqueryui since the plugin is not from jqueryui.Sorry if i am wrong..

Comment: jqueryui is needed when you want to use basic controles like datepicker,autocomplete,tabs,tooltip,dialoge box etc. If u dont need the controles then u can skip this. The plugin is from jquery.

Answer (score 0):

<(removeMe)script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
<(removeMe)/script>'

You can add your all kind of jquery pulgin like this in your aspx page.