# Edit mode in grid view can't find the textbox id using getElementById()

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview, datepicker

In my `gridview` I have a date column and in edit mode, I place there a date picker. The date picker is in javascript which uses a `getElementById()` to get/set the value on the textbox.

This is the code of my `gridview` with the date picker if in edit mode:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Effective Date" HeaderStyle-CssClass="allWidth160" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ControlStyle-CssClass="txtCommon allWidth80 txtCenter">
     <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblEffDate"  Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EFF_DATE").ToString()%>'>
          </asp:Label>
     </ItemTemplate>
     <EditItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox ClientIDMode="Static" ID="EffDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("EFF_DATE") %>' />
          <img alt="Calendar" src="../Images/DateTimePickerImg/cal.gif" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="javascript: NewCssCal('txtEffDate')" />
     </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I included the javascript file in the HEAD:

```
<script src="../Library/DateTimePicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When I click the image calendar it has an error somewhere in DateTimePicker.js file which leads to this code:

```
exDateTime = document.getElementById(pCtrl).value;
```

Where `pCtrl` is txtEffDate.

Error: **Object required**

It seems that it cannot see the object `txtEffDate` thats why it throws that error. I think that when it is in edit mode, it only show its drawing (the textbox appear) in the browser but its ID is still missing. Any thoughts? TIA

Comment: see the generated id of the textbox in the html on the browser.

Comment: In what way can I do that?

Comment: You can either right-click/view source (in nearly any browser) or right-click directly on the textbox and inspect element (in chrome or firefox).

Comment: by pressing f12 key in the browser.

Comment: Oh I see. The ID of the textbox for the date picker is generated automatically so the paramater (txtEffDate or EffDate) is wrong. ID is like **grdViewEmpList_ctl02_EffDate**. Now, what code should I put in the parameter to get the right autogenerated ID of the textbox?

Comment: @Satpal. Error sir, **Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'EffDate' does not exist in the current context**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a new function and pass this .Like this.

```
 onclick = "javascript: NewCssCalClick(this)"
```

And in js make a new function NewCssCalClick.Like this.

```
function NewCssCalClick(sender) {

    var id = $(sender).prev()[0].id;
    NewCssCal(id);
}
```

Note: You need to add jquery plugin for $ and prev to work

Comment: Same result sir. Error: **Object required**

Comment: jQuery, you mean like: `jquerymin.js`?

Comment: i have just edited the code and put [0] after prev. Check it again. also alert the id and what is it.

Comment: read this answer for adding jquery file.You can skip the UI and Css. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20511635/using-jquery-plugin-in-aspx-page/20512316#20512316

Comment: This one did the job. Cheers sir :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you can use

```
 $("[id*='EffDate']")

 exDateTime = $("[id*='EffDate']").val();
```

to get the textbox. As you will have only one text-box at a time. Because you might be editing only one row at a time.

Comment: It is javascript sir. I need to put the right ID in the parameter of `onclick="javascript: NewCssCal('txtEffDate')"` as I mention in the other comments.

Answer (score 0):

modify the edit item template like below:

add id="imgCalander" runat="server" attributes to calander image and onclick attribute like onclick="fnShowCalander(this.id);"

in javascript define new function like below:

```
    function fnShowCalander(senderID) {
        NewCssCal(senderID.replace('imgCalander', 'EffDate'));
    }

</script>
```